# Why NavLink does not add active class to dynamic route in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am trying to understand why my `NavLink` elements do not add `"active"` class when dynamic route is specified.

I have `NavLink` navigation like this:

```
<ul className='nav-links'>
  <li>
    <NavLink to='/'>All Users</NavLink>
  </li>
  <li>
    <NavLink to='/uid/places'>My Places</NavLink>
  </li>
  <li>
    <NavLink to='/places/new'>New Place</NavLink>
  </li>
  <li>
    <NavLink to='/auth'>Authenticate</NavLink>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And here is React router setup:

```
const Layout = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <MainNavigation />
      <Outlet />
    </>
  )
}

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    element: <Layout />,
    children: [
      {
        path: '/',
        element: <Users />
      },
      {
        path: '/:userId/places',
        element: <UserPlaces />
      },
      {
        path: '/places/new',
        element: <NewPlace />
      }
    ]
  }
])
```

So when I type e.g. `"/2332/places"`, no `"active"` class is added. When I type `"/places/new"`, `"active"` class is added to `<NavLink to='/places/new'>New Place</NavLink>`

Can you please explain me what is wrong?

Comment: Which version of react router are you using?

Comment: Your code works as expected here in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/why-navlink-does-not-add-active-class-to-dynamic-route-in-react-cll04u?file=/src/App.js). What exactly is the issue you are seeing? Are there any errors? What are your exact reproduction steps to produce any issues? How are you verifying/validating any `"active"` class is (*or isn't*) added to the link element?

Comment: I use React router 6.4. @DrewReese thanks for condesandbox. What if user put into url /2362/places or /98454/places or /test/places etc? I want active class to be added to NavLink even for these cases. I hope it makes any sense.

Comment: @MichalUrban Those all are working and matched/made active in the sandbox I linked. Are you experiencing something *other than* this expected behavior? Is there perhaps a misunderstanding what the `NavLink` does? What ***exactly*** are you doing and what are you expecting?

Comment: When i type /98454/places or /test/places or /2362/places into url i want this NavLink to have `active` class: `<NavLink to='/uid/places'>My Places</NavLink>`